# How to load Gist code without getting async error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, asynchronous

I am currently working with angular and rails on a new blog for myself and I am stuck. I used `ng-bind-html` for injecting the code from my backend.

Now I fixed it using my own directive.

I am currently getting the following error when I am trying to import a code example from Github's Gist service:

```
Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

What is the reason and how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: seems pretty obvious, you can't use `document.write` after page loads or it will wipe out everything in the page

Comment: Need more information/code sample/library used to help you. I got into similar problem. I used [gist-embed](https://github.com/blairvanderhoof/gist-embed) library. I've to recompile binded html with ```gist()``` when used ng-bind-html. Also have a look at https://github.com/pasupulaphani/angular-gist-embed , it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old but I stumbled across it while searching for the error. You can include https://github.com/blairvanderhoof/gist-embed/ in your project and then write a directive to apply the change:

```
yourApp.directive('gistDirective', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('someAngularVariable', function(){
            angular.element('[data-gist-id]').gist();
        });

    }
});
```

Then

```
<section gist-directive>
                <article>
                    <div ng-bind-html="trustHtml(someAngularVariable.body)"></div>
                </article>
    </section>
```